# Safely adding a `sum` method to Array class

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I'm doing a lot of array summing in my code, so I'm thinking of monkey-patching the Array class to include a sum method (that sums all the elements in the array):

```
class Array
  def sum
    self.inject{ |s, t| s + t }
  end
end
```

However, I've never monkey-patched anything in shared code before, and I doubt that this is a "safe" thing to do (e.g., maybe someone else has already defined a `sum` method in `Array`).

So what's the best way to be able to sum arrays in the code I'm writing, without having to write `arr.inject{ |s, t| s + t }` every time? Is there a safe way to monkey-patch? Can I use a module somehow? Or should I just write a helper method somewhere that takes in an array and returns the sum (i.e., `def sum_array(arr); return arr.inject{ |s, t| s + t }; end`)? (Or is there some totally other approach?)

Comment: I personally monkey-patch (though I monkey-patch in `Enumerable#sum`, not just `Array#sum`) but of course any monkey-patch is not 'safe'. Without something like [remix](https://github.com/banister/remix) your safest bet is clearly a helper method.

Comment: `self` is the default receiver in Ruby, so you can leave that off. Your block is equivalent to `&:+`, so you can just as well write the method as `inject(&:+)`. `inject` even accepts a symbol argument itself and makes the block conversion for you, so you can get rid of the `&` as well. Note also that you don't actually depend on the fact that `self` is an `Array`, only that it has an `inject` method, so you can lift that up into `Enumerable` and end up with `module Enumerable; def sum; reduce(:+) end end`.

Comment: "maybe someone else has already defined a `sum` method in `Array`" -- Indeed, there is one in [`ActiveSupport`](https://GitHub.Com/Rails/Rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L38-63). Which BTW is more flexible than yours and handles the corner case of an empty collection better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inject` can actually take a symbol argument, so all you really have to write is `arr.inject(:+)`, which I think doesn't really need a shorter form.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494

Comment: I prefer to use the synonymous `arr.reduce(:+)` because I find reduce to be a more intuitive name for the fxn.  Definitely the best way to handle this, by either name.

Comment: Smalltalk uses `inject:into:` and `collect:`, which is why `reduce` and `map` have the respective synonyms in Ruby :-)

Comment: Well, `inject: aValue into: aBlock` makes sense when you read it out loud, `inject(a_value, &a_block)` doesn't read nearly as nice. Really, Ruby's `inject` is equivalent to two *different* functions, typically called `fold` (for the two argument form of `inject`) and `reduce` or `fold1` (for the one-argument form). In this particular case it is used as `reduce` and I prefer to spell it that way when used that way, and `inject` otherwise.

Comment: @Jörg: while that is obviously correct, it still doesn't change the fact that the aliases are there for old Smalltalkers. Personally I'm just too lazy to switch between `reduce` and `inject` depending on context, so I always use the latter. I never use `collect` though, I find `map` just makes more sense. All in all a matter of preference I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

You could always subclass array and define it there. Say if you had `AdderArray < Array` you could find the sum like this:

```
AdderArray.new(a1).sum
```

Or you could just define a helper library:

```
ArrayHelper.sum(a1)
```

It's really up to you what to do. I don't even see a problem with monkey patching (what's the chance someone is going to make an array method called `sum` that doesn't sum?). Even if a conflict does end up occurring, you could always rename it to `sum_members` after the fact.